# Where can I find a list of GCP cloud builders?

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

The official page https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders says look at "The complete list of supported builders for Cloud Build" at [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders](https://cloud.google.%20com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders).

However that seems incorrect as the [mvn directory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/mvn) only mentions `maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim` and Google does support jdk 8. Also, the plain `mvn` builder uses a Maven version of 3.6.1 or newer, as it supports the `-ntp` flag.

Is there somewhere I can look up the versions of the newest and various other available versions at least for Maven builders?

Comment: If you look at the link you supplied for the Maven cloud builder you can see the Dockerfile which is used to create the container image that will run.  As you see, it is about as no-op as possible.  You can create your own Cloud Builder container and put it in your own registry and use that.

Answer (score 2):

As documented for the [Cloud Build Maven builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/mvn)

> You should consider instead using an official maven image and specifying the mvn entrypoint:

```
steps:
- name: maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim
  entrypoint: 'mvn'
  args: ['install']
```

And use **any** image from [Maven Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/) repository.

> This allows you to use any supported version of Maven with any supported JDK version.